# Angular 7: Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging

Tags: angular, google-chrome, safari, angular7

Everything was working fine in my Angular application. But now suddenly I am getting the following error and my browser got stuck.

> Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging. See `<URL>`. Command line switch `--disable-ipc-flooding-protection` can be used to bypass the protection

What I done in last 2 days is updated npm. Run `npm audit fix` to fix vulnerabilities. After that I am getting this error.

[image]

It is looping and I cannot access my Application through browser.

I have added some code too. May be some code causes looping?

Comment: Sounds like your app is going in a loop. I doubt this has to do with NPM. You need to open the debugger and step through your code execution.

Comment: hi @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane Yes the issue is solved by refactoring a block of code that looks like going into a loop. But I didn't get this error before (its been long time) even the same code exists. Strange! May be its to deal with cache or something. I will inform here if the issue still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the issue is solved by refactoring a block of code that looks like going into a loop. I don't have this error before with the same code.
Now solved. But the real reason is unknown. Strange! May be its to deal with cache or something.

Comment: Hi guys, I am removing the marking of correct answer from here because still after some days I am getting this error again, still no clue what is the correct solution.

Comment: We are seeing the same error in Angular 9 on one Chrome browser coming from `gtm.js` causing that browser to freeze. Other Chrome browsers seem to be OK. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is en error in the router guards. try and follow the link bellow.

https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/1293

Comment: Can you inline the answer here instead of just linking externally?

Answer (score 1):

[image: in this image you can see i added return and 1 return is down also.]

in this image you can see i added return and 1 return is down also, so thats causing me this issue once i removed return line from canactivate so my code is working properly

Comment: Please don't use images for information that is easily communicated in text. Images are not friendly to search or copy & paste or visually impaired people.